# Основа в предложении

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, основа

Помогите определить раз и навсегда  :) грамматическую основу в таком предложении

> Очень часто всего один голос может оказаться решающим.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

"Очень часто всего один голос может оказаться решающим"

(Кто? Что?) голос-подлежащее

(что о нём говорится?) может оказаться решающим - составное именное сказуемое

Answer (score 1):

Грамматическая основа в этом предложении - *голос может оказаться*.
*Голос* - это подлежащее, выраженное именем существительным.
*Может оказаться* - это составное глагольное сказуемое, выраженное модальным глаголом-связкой (выражает грамматическое значение) *мочь* и инфинитивом (выражает лексическое (смысловое) значение) оказаться.
Глагол- связка и лексический глагол в СГС должны относиться к одному субъекту (подлежащему): *может* голос и *оказывается* также голос.

Comment: Какую же информацию несёт глагол оказаться? Оказался - т.е. появился, пришёл? Главная информация - что голос решающий (был решающим, оказался решающим, мог оказаться решающим)

Comment: Да, наверное, вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Голос может оказаться решающим. Если вопрос от глагола задаётся к прилагательному- значит это прилагательное автоматически присоединяется к сказуемому (сис).

Answer (score 1):

*Очень часто всего один голос может оказаться решающим.*

**Сказуемое:** *может оказаться решающим.* Осложненная связка: *может оказаться*, именная часть: *решающим*.

По поводу подлежащего **есть сомнения**: слово *один* может быть прилагательным (со значением "единственный") или числительным.

При варианте **с числительным** подлежащее: **всего один голос**, счетный оборот "один голос" + частица "всего".

При варианте **с прилагательным**:  всего единственный **голос** может оказаться решающим.  По смыслу получается повтор: голос (какой?) "всего единственный".

Comment: Вариант с прилагательным Вы сами отвергаете, правильно? Значит подлежащее — *всего один голос*. Я верно понял?

Comment: Всего один голос- не счётный оборот, счётный оборот (слитное сочетание) - сочетание числительного с родительным падежом, на основе управления, а всего один - согласование. Всего один - определение. Ничем синтаксически не отличается от такого предложения: "Очень часто единственный  голос может оказаться решающим". Единственный -определение, или Вы его тоже относите к подлежащему?

Comment: М_Г, Я думаю. что подлежащим является "всего один голос", но у меня нет абсолютной уверенности. Я бы так ответила на вопрос, но ведь большое количество участников считают, что это "голос"

Comment: По-моему, числительное "один" может входить в счетный оборот: ОДИН, 3. Количество. Отрежьте о. метр ткани. Купил о. литр молока и о. килограмм масла. Какое здесь расстояние? - О. километр. Дело в том, что "один" - особое числительное, оно не управляет Р.п. существительного, а согласуется с ним.

Comment: @Людмила и Ксения. Пытаюсь разбраться. Если "два голоса" - счетный оборот, то и "один голос" тоже, разве не так? "Всего два голоса могут оказаться решающими". Где тут подлежащее?

Comment: А Вы как считаете? Я думаю: один голос или всего один голос, ведь речь идет о подсчете голосов, поэтому это скорее числительное.

Comment: Строго говоря, счётный оборот -
 сочетание счётного слова с сущ. в родительном падеже. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/587/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Однако в вузах, не называя счётным оборотом, включают в подлежащее числительное один при подсчёте голосов, но в нашем примере я вижу не слитное количественное сочетание, а свободное сочетание подлежащего голос и определения всего один, потому что "всего один" несёт ещё и качественную характеристику - единственный, слабый, его можно заменить прилагательным. В школе это однозначно определение, а в вузах разные подходы, но там выделяются трёхчленные сочетания, а в школе нет. В вузе "два крутых парня" - всё подлежащее (прилагательное в середине счётного оборота), а в школе только "два парня".

Comment: Не буду спорить со "строгим определением", а также обсуждать разное понимание счетного оборота в школе и в вузе. Но вот простой пример: У тебя будет один чемодан или два чемодана? Неужели одно сочетание является счетным оборотом, а другое нет. Или еще пример:  Этот кандидат набрал на один голос больше. Вроде бы здесь речь идет о подсчете голосов, чем же это не счетный оборот?

Comment: Рознеталь в *§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)* рассматривает и числительные, оканчивающиеся на один (не Р.п.). Ответ на вопрос "А Вы как считаете?". Думаю, речь идет о количестве голосов (что один, что два — нет разницы), а "единственный" (скажите еще "одинокий")  — как-то неестественно здесь.